# No sound from speakers, but headphones work

Tags: sound

I have had a problem with my sound for a while now.  Sound comes from my headphones, but not from my speakers.  I am running Ubuntu 11.10 on a Compaq 320.   I have searched around, but none of the threads have worked, some had made it worse (no sound at all, but I managed to get back to where I am now).
Any help would on how to fix this would be great.

Answer (score 10):

I found a post in this [Ubuntu forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2197749) answer #2 with a weird solution that works for me.

Boot the system, log in, close the laptop screen, wait for a few seconds, and open it again. Log back into the system and problem solved!!!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: On mine, it works a while, then soon it is get muted again ( no sound ) after around 1 minutes :(

Comment: For now it worked for me

Comment: @Bayu , same is happening with me. How did you resolve this?

Comment: @Priyanka , please read again my comment carefully. It works only a *while* for me. Perhaps we should ask judasane ( comment just right below me ), looks like he had success.

Comment: Hey @judasane please let us know the workaround.

Comment: does not work, ..

Comment: holy shit it worked. i simply restarted my laptop. so stupid :D this is some "IT Crowd" stuff

Comment: This "Boot up and log in. Then with the everything running, close your laptop screen and open it back up." works for me in 2024.

Answer (score 5):

try using these commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get purge linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop
```

Reboot.

if this not help trying running [this](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=0058487d2078af8416a0dbf623f69efe20feaff3) script

Comment: Hey Gaurav, Tried the commands but no luck.  he script seems to be outdated for 10.04.   would it still work for 11.10

Comment: Hey @twister_void, I suggest you to specify on your answer that the display manager to be used is lightdm by default, because these lines - `sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop` - could lead to set the gdm3, where you know better than me that lightdm is the default one

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18. After many many other attempts!

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit this file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and then add a line in its end. Use the following commands:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Now add the following line at its end:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

Now reboot your computer. It should solve your problem.

Further information:

- hxxp://www.computerandyou.net/2011/06/how-to-solve-no-sound-through-laptop-integrated-speakers-in-ubuntu-11-04

> The link that was posted here is no longer safe to use, and has had its actual *link* components stripped.  The original link is left here for historical purposes, though the link is defused.

Comment: Hey Abishek,   after sing the command, gedit didn't open, so i couldnt add the other line.  Why wouldnt gedit open?

Comment: I was able to open gedit with the command (had to take out the '&' and the end).

Comment: But after adding the line,  there was still no sound from the speakers.

Comment: @forrest did you try the solution given in the link? It may depend on the sound card as well... the solution worked for me..

Comment: YEa, no luck from the link.   my soundcard is '0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: HDA Generic [HDA Generic]"  so its pretty straight forward

Comment: This may sound foolish.. but could you check in the Sound settings if it is not muted .. happened to me couple of years back.. just guessing.. :P

Comment: Been there done that, no luck.  Sound cards are recognised. This has happened to me before, and i used to be able to fix it, but now the regular fixes arnt working and its been a few months.  Bloody annoying.   just upgraded to 12.04 too hoping that that might do the trick but no luck

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on an Aspire.

What's worse I convinced someone to use Ubuntu! Egg on my face!

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)

$ cat /proc/asound/version
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.24.

$ head -n 1 /proc/asound/card*/codec#*
==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 <==
Codec: Realtek ALC888

==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#1 <==
Codec: LSI ID 1040

==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#2 <==
Codec: Intel Cantiga HDMI

$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC888 Digital [ALC888 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ uname -a
Linux salvatore-Aspire-7730 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The `alsa-base.conf` does not exist.

Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit

Tried this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio indicator-sound
```

Now audio comes out of both headphone and speaker.

Answer (score 1):

on my lenovo this works:

- shut down the laptop
- take off the battery
- press the power button, to empty the capacitors or wait for 30 seconds
- put the battery back
- power on and enjoy sound in headphones again

Comment: It is not necessary to wait, without the battery press the power button, to empty the capacitors, after that, put the battery back. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

I find that sometimes all I have to do is choose the correct output by just going to `System Setting` and then click on `Sound` on the output tab.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried that out to no avail,  however the 'test speaker' didnt make a sound, but i had a video going on youtube that I could hear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Go to "System Settings" select "Sound" and then select "Headphones" as the option in the the "Connector" drop down menu list.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the sound settings for USB using:

1. Go to sound settings from the volume options on the right.
2. I you have plugged in USB speaker then it shows setting options as Analog Output Analog Audio.
3. Click on it and adjust volume.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a brand new laptop Asus R417B. I installed Ubuntu 18.04  over the windows disk. Windows had never been installed let alone run, so the speakers had not been used at all.

In pavucontrol the speakers and the headphones are listed, and the volume bar showed sound being played. The speaker test did not produce sound at the speakers. The headphones, when plugged in, worked perfectly.

**My fix was trying to try audio over HDMI** on the television. The laptop speakers started to work as soon as the laptop was connected over HDMI. Even after disconnecting the HDMI the speakers kept working. Even after a complete power shutdown and restart.

Then the HDMI sound seemed not to work, but that was easy to fix with fiddling with the profiles in pavucontrol.

My conclusion is that the problem was a bug (at least definitely not a feature) in initializing the hardware/software with the speakers.