# Ubuntu 18.04 Asus Xonar DG sound card not recognized

Tags: 18.04, sound, soundcard

After having problem with my motherboard sound card, which worked capriciously, I added `Asus Xonar DG` but still can not get any sound out of  my ubuntu 18.04 machine.

`alsamixer` does not show the card as [it should](https://askubuntu.com/a/687812/205100).

```
#lsmod | grep snd
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  2
snd_hda_codec_ca0132    90112  1
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_intel          40960  15
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_hda_codec         126976  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_ca0132
snd_hda_core           81920  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_ca0132
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  7 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_ca0132
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    81920  38 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_ca0132,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

And the Asus driver page [does not list](https://www.asus.com/us/Sound-Cards/Xonar_DG/HelpDesk_Download/) Linux as an option, whilde alsa page [says that](https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Vendor-Asus) it is supported since kernel 3.14

I have also tweaked `Sound > Settings` but to no avail.

So left clueless. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it turned out that the card was not properly inserted on a PCIe 16.

I changed the carded to another PCIe 16 slut and fastened the card with a screw, then chosen alsamixer as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598759/asus-xonar-dgx-recognized-but-no-sound/687812#687812), and also chosen `Analog Output-CM187881` in `Sound > Setting` as my output, it works like a charm!

[image]