# Internal speakers started working after pairing bluetooth

Tags: sound, speakers

just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my new HP Pavillion (15-cs3044nw) and had an issue of not working internal speaker while headphones worked just fine.

I went through quite a lot of threads and tutorials with no luck (i.e [No sound from speakers, but headphones work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117842/no-sound-from-speakers-but-headphones-work) , https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) with no luck. System behaved like everything with the speakers was just OK (the bar showing sound level was changing while music was playing etc. but there were no sound).

All of a sudden speakers started working when I tried to connect bluetooth headphones (which did not work - they paired but did not connect, but it's not the case here).

Later I found that someone had similar issue - internal speakers started to work after connecting HDMI. Maybe it's some kind of a clue for someone having same issue in the future.

Do you know if there is any log I can check what happened to the speakers? And what to look for in this log.