# Built in speaker not working on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

The title says it all. I bought a clevo laptop and the builtin speaker is not working.

I tried every possible solutions here : [No sound from speakers, but headphones work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117842/no-sound-from-speakers-but-headphones-work) but non of them worked.

The sound works on my USB Headset, and on my monitor, but not on the builtin speaker. I think it may be a problem with alsa because pavucontrol shows that there is sound but I can't hear it.

The built in speaker was working when I turned on the laptop for the first time with windows preinstalled on it.

I don't really know how the linux sound system works. Please let me know if you need more information to help me (log files, etc)